After caching a page in Next.js, the data fetched from the server doesn't update
On this page, data fetched from the server. When I first render this page or reload it, all the data is displayed correctly, but if I go to another page and then go back without reloading, the old data is displayed.
I'm guessing the page is cached along with the fetched data and this is a problem.
Page code:
async function GetAboutTablesData(): Promise<{ miscs: IMisc[]; contacts: IContact[]; socials: ISocial[]; } | false> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/admin/about`, {
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-store",
        })
        if (response.ok) return response.json()
        return false
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return false
    }
}

export default async function AdminContentAbout(): Promise<React.ReactElement> {
    const aboutTablesData: { miscs: IMisc[]; contacts: IContact[]; socials: ISocial[]; } | false = await GetAboutTablesData()

    return (
        <main className="admin-content-about">
            <section className="navigator">
                <div className="navigator-path">
                    <Link href="/admin" className="navigator-title-link">
                        <h2>Navigator</h2>
                    </Link>
                    <span className="navigator-char">&#62;</span>
                    <Link href="/admin/content" className="navigator-title-link">
                        <h2>Content</h2>
                    </Link>
                    <span className="navigator-char">&#62;</span>
                    <h1 className="navigator-title">About</h1>
                </div>
            </section>
            {aboutTablesData && (<Elementor originFormData={aboutTablesData} />)}
            {aboutTablesData === false && (<p>Server error</p>)}
        </main>
    )
}

I expect that every time this page is visited there will be a fetch of data.
I have already tried to put properties in the fetch request like cache: no-cache and next: {revalidate: 0} but they had no effect.
I also tried add export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' and export const revalidate = 0 but they had no effect too.
For now, the only working option is updating the page using window.location.reload() but I think it's wrong.
What needs to be done to ensure that data is always fetched from the server?

Go back with the browser back button?

Including back button

This also happens when routing between pages using the NextJS Link tag
